# Шаблон для текстового редактора Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, редактор-текста

Как в Visual Studio 2013, создать шаблон в текстовом редакторе. На подобие того как делает решарпер. То есть желаемый результат: Нажал custom Hotkeys(например Ctrl+1+2) и в коде вставились строки соответствующие данному шаблону?

Comment: Вот есть описание: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, то что надо!